# Run function from string and parse variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, arguments

Let's say I have an object with this markup:

```
var obj = {
    cat: function(string, bool, NEEDTHIS) {
        console.log(string, bool, NEEDTHIS);
    }
}
```

Lets say I have the function, with it's variables as an attribute on a button which I have NO control over how it's generated. Example:

`<button type="button" onclick="obj.cat('foo', true, 'dog');">PRINT</button>`

I need to run this function on the button, but remove the attribute so that I can parse my own attribute.

So I'd strip the attribute 'onclick', store it in a string like so:

`var function = "obj.cat('foo', true);";`

surely there's a way to just add in another argument without literally altering the string.

I'm also stuck on how I could run the function as it is from the string.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use eval

```
var function = "obj.cat('foo', true);";
eval(function);
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer how I can pass additional arguments to the function